# Struggling to center align icons from font awesome

Tags: html, css

I've tried many ways to align 4 icons to he center of the page, but i failed in all of them, pls help me.
ill put a print of the icons

html

```
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4e49a073fe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="icons">
       <i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-file" ></i>
       <i class="fa-brands fa-square-github" ></i>
       <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope" ></i>
  </div>

</body>
```

css

```
dont have cause all I tried didnt worked
```

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7nKb.png)

Comment: write this css ``` .icons{ text-align:center }```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use flexbox to make it center the page both vertically and horizontally and assign `height: 100%` to your div

```
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```